# I execute my function, and it returns a function () { [native code] }

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I execute my function, and it returns a function () { [native code] }

```
function Simpan() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('Input Form');
  var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName('Database');

  var nomorinput = shtinput.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var namaitem = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();
  var jumlahitem = shtinput.getRange('D7').getValue;
  var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D9').getValue;
  
  var baris = shtdb.getRange('E1').getValue();
  baris += 1;
  var rangeisi = shtdb.getRange('A' + baris + ':D'+ baris);
  rangeisi.setValues([[nomorinput,namaitem,jumlahitem,tgl]]);
  
}
```

It should show the input from the sheet

Comment: how do you ```execute``` your function?

Comment: i insert the script to the image which will takes all input data to database automatically after i click the image. sorry still new to explain this problem

Comment: in ```javascript``` you can call a function (in your case) like ```Simpan``` which returns the definition of the function you called instead of executing it, to execute the function, you should instead call ```Simpan()```

Comment: i use spreadsheet

Comment: ```app-script``` of ```google spreadsheet``` works based on ```javascript```,  and follows the same rules.

Comment: hum, now that you have mentioned ```after i click the image```, I assume you want to make it a button. In that case it is right that you don't need ```()``` after function name, since google don't let us pass args to this kind of UI calls...

Comment: I think the issue appears to be the ```.getValue()``` method missing their ```()``` in some of your code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Simpan() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('Input Form');
  var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName('Database');

  var nomorinput = shtinput.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var namaitem = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();
  var jumlahitem = shtinput.getRange('D7').getValue();
  var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D9').getValue();
  
  var baris = shtdb.getRange('E1').getValue();
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I see where is the problem, check the comments below:

```js
function Simpan() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('Input Form');
  var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName('Database');

  var nomorinput = shtinput.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var namaitem = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();
  var jumlahitem = shtinput.getRange('D7').getValue; // << you cannot call .getValue without following ()
  var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D9').getValue; // << you cannot call .getValue without following ()
  
  var baris = shtdb.getRange('E1').getValue();
  baris += 1;
  var rangeisi = shtdb.getRange('A' + baris + ':D'+ baris);
  rangeisi.setValues([[nomorinput,namaitem,jumlahitem,tgl]]);
  
}
```

As I mentioned earlier,

when you call function (or method) in javascript, if you call them without `()`, it returns the definition of that function (or method) instead of executing them.

to make this code work as your expectation, you have to change it into:

```js
function Simpan() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtinput = Sheet.getSheetByName('Input Form');
  var shtdb = Sheet.getSheetByName('Database');

  var nomorinput = shtinput.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var namaitem = shtinput.getRange('D5').getValue();
  var jumlahitem = shtinput.getRange('D7').getValue();
  var tgl = shtinput.getRange('D9').getValue();
  
  var baris = shtdb.getRange('E1').getValue();
  baris += 1;
  var rangeisi = shtdb.getRange('A' + baris + ':D'+ baris);
  rangeisi.setValues([[nomorinput,namaitem,jumlahitem,tgl]]);
  
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. very simple problem, but i got so confused about it. it's already run very well.